# " [Linter] Error running HLint " ? hlint doesn't work on Atom

Tags: macos, haskell, atom-editor, hlint

I installed 'linter 2.2.0' on Atom (this also installed: busy-signal 1.4.3, intentions 1.1.5, linter-ui-default 1.6.10). Then I installed 'linter-hlint 2.0.0' , however it doesn't work. I get an error saying: "[Linter] Error running HLint , see console for more info."

I know that I have to "specify the path to hlint" in settings but I can't even find the path. When I open my terminal (using a Mac) and type "which hlint" there is no output, just a new line.

Can anybody tell me what's happening and what I can do?

Comment: Did you install hlint? Or did you only install the atom plugin? If not try `stack install hlint` assuming you have `stack` installed.

Comment: I just went into atom and under Preferences -> Install -> selected `linter-hlint`. I just tried running `stack install hlint` on my terminal and it downloaded some stuff but gave me : `No compiler found, expected minor version match with ghc-8.0.2 (x86_64) (based on resolver setting in /Users/benf76/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml)`.

Comment: I guess I don't have `stack` installed, I just ran `stack setup` and it says : "Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location". What I don't understand is why I need all this. Before I just used the command `ghci` and ran any Haskell code

Comment: I installed `stack` then ran `stack install hlint` and at the end said : "Installation path /Users/benf76/.local/bin not found on the PATH environment variable". typing `which hlint` still gives me nothing.

Comment: First install stack if you haven't done so far. Then remove every haskell related package from Atom. Then install the [atom-haskell](https://atom.io/packages/atom-haskell) package. It will simply install almost all needed tools including the linter.

Comment: the reason for those difficulties are: haskell-plattform is shipping with ghc-8.2.1 (a recent change), stack is not yet using ghc-8.2.1 in their main repository - thus you get an error about compiler mismatch. The problem with your $PATH I do not know - might be that you need to add /Users/benf76/.local/bin to your PATH because that is where stack installs the executables which it builds.

Comment: thank you Redu , and @epsilonhalbe !